# Write attributes from list to var

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following piece of code:

```
var Attributes = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == PwRetreival.uId).Select(u => new { u.Name, u.UserId }).ToList();
user.Name = Attributes(SOMETHING?)
user.UserId = Attributes(SOMETHING?)
```

I have no idea how i would write the selected attributes to my model variables. I guess it doesn't know the type of the attribute when i write it like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Attributes` now is a list of an anonymous type containing `Name` and `UserId`.

```
user.Name = Attributes[0].Name
user.UserId = Attributes[0].UserId
```

... Would get the name and id of the `first` user, if the list contains at least 1 element.

You can also do:

```
foreach(var user in Attributes)
{
    // var userName = user.Name;
    // var userId = user.UserId;
}
```

... to iterate through all users. In this case, you don't even need the `ToList()` method in your query;

**However, it seems like this query should return just one user**. In this case, you can change your query to

```
var Attributes = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == PwRetreival.uId).Select(u => new { u.Name, u.UserId }).FirstOrDefault();
```

... and now `Attributes` has only 1 object with a `Name` and a `UserId` and you can access it like:

```
user.Name = Attributes.Name
user.UserId = Attributes.UserId
```

As pointed out by @Chris, if you can assume that your query is going to return 0 or 1 element, you should use `SingleOrDefault()`. If it should return just 1 element, you should use `Single()`. If the result contains more elements than it will throw an exception. And when you use `XOrDefault` you should always check for null afterwards.

Comment: That is great! - Thank you very much :-)

Comment: If the query returns just one user you should use `SingleOrDefault`. That way if your assumption is wrong you will have an error thrown. Also any time you use `OrDefault` you should *always* have a null check to check for the default condition. If you know it will never be null then you should just use `Single` and let it throw an exception for you at that point if it found no matches.

Answer (score 1):

This line returns a list of anonymous objects:

```
var Attributes = db.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserId == PwRetreival.uId).Select(u => new { u.Name, u.UserId }).ToList();
```

Therefore, you can either iterate the list or index it:

```
user.Name = Atrributes[0].Name;
```

**NOTE:** Since you are getting the item by its Id, I would use `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` and not `Where`. See below for more.

---

Use `Single`

If you expect a single item to be returned, then do not use `Where` but use `Single` instead. Then you can do this:

```
user.Name = Attributes.Name;
```

---

Use `SingleOrDefaut`

If you expect a single item or no item, then use `SingleOrDefault` but check the value before using it like this:

```
if (Attributes != null)
{
    user.Name = Attributes.Name;
}
```

---

There are also `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Last` and `LastOrDefault`.

Answer (score 1):

As it is of type `List`, you need to use `FirstOrDefault()` to get the first record from the list (assuming that your `Where` clause have enough conditions to get the exact record you want).

```
var Attributes = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserId == PwRetreival.uId).Select(u => new { u.Name, u.UserId }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

if (Attributes != null)
{
    user.Name = Attributes.Name;
    user.UserId = Attributes.UserId;
}
```

Comment: Do note that if you are using `FirstOrDefault` you should put a null check in as well to protect against the "default" case. Also in the case of youre assumption that the `Where` clause gets the exact record you want then `SingleOrDefault` would be better since having multiple returns would be an error case.